# PHP SSH move file to another directory

Tags: php, ssh, ssh2-sftp

I have a lengthy PHP script that takes a form, outputs it as a csv file, uploads it to a remote server and then moves it to another directory on the server. Everything is working except for moving it to a remote folder after upload. Here is what I have:

```
    $connection = ssh2_connect('server.url', 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'pwd');
    ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/var/app/current/Folder/LocalFolder/File.csv', '/home/user/RemoteFolder1/File.csv', 0644);

    //here is where I am stuck
    mv /home/user/RemoteFolder1/File.csv /home/user/RemoteFolder2/File.csv

    //I think this exits sufficiently, is there a better way
    ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');
    unset($connection);
```

Why do I need to move it and not just upload it into the second folder?Same question I asked. From remote server's admin 'it is easy for there to be a race condition where we will read a file while you are uploading the file. This will result in use receiving only part of the file.' they need it to completely upload, then move to the second folder
How do I move it from RemoteFolder1 to RemoteFolder2? I dont know the correct command, so far `mv` and `move_uploaded_file` have not worked

Comment: Why `scp` it to one folder, just to move it into another?

Comment: Same question I asked. From remote server's admin 'it is easy for there to be a race condition where we will read a file while you are uploading the file. This will result in use receiving only part of the file.' they need it to completely upload, then move to the second folder

Comment: This is clearly not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I suspect you are wanting to run `ssh2_exec($connection, 'mv /home/... /home/...');`.

Comment: Any help is much appreciated. Again, I can create and upload the .csv file, once it is uploaded to /RemoteFolder1/ I need to move it to /RemoteFolder2/

Comment: @Phylogenesis, thank you! that worked perfectly. If you would like to add it as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot add answers to closed questions.

Comment: Damn, that sucks. I didn't think it was a duplicate. I really appreciate the help, I learned something new. it was the ssh2_exec wrapper. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a dupe. The OP wants to move a file on a remote server via ssh.